# For ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to S$, prove that if $R$ is a field and $\phi(R)\neq \left \{0_{S} \right \}$, then $\phi(R)$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

Could someone please verify whether I am missing anything important in my proof solution?

> For ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to S$, prove that if $R$ is a field and $\phi(R)\neq \left \{0_{S}  \right \}$, then $\phi(R)$ is a field.

Let $R$ be a field and let $\phi(R)\neq \left \{0_{S}  \right \}$. Then $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and every nonzero element of $R$ is a unit. Since $\phi(R)$ is a subring of $S$, then $\phi(R)$ inherits the commutative property and $1_{S}=\phi(1_{R})\in \phi(R)$, so $\phi(R)$ has identity. Finally, since $uu^{-1}=1_{R}$ for all nonzero $u\in R$, if $0\neq \phi(u)\in \phi(R)$, then $\phi(u)(\phi(u))^{-1}=\phi(u)\phi(u^{-1})=\phi(uu^{-1})=\phi(1_{R})=1_{S}$ Then every nonzero element of $\phi(R)$ is a unit. By definition, $\phi(R)$ is a field.

> The last part, I am not sure whether it is logically correct.

Comment: It is logically correct.

Comment: Alternatively you could just reason that $\ker\phi\neq R$, therefore $\ker\phi=\{0\}$, and by the first isomorphism theorem, $R$ is isomorphic to $\phi(R)$.

Comment: Actually, you should show that $\phi(u^{-1})\phi(u)=\phi(u)\phi(u^{-1})=1_S$ (as you have done mostly). This then states that $\phi(u^{-1})$ is an inverse of $\phi(u)$.

Comment: @Clayton Thank you for taking the time to reply. I would think I just need to check one of those since $\phi(R)$ is commutative. Then is mine okay or is it still missing something?

Comment: @numerical: but you don’t know that $S$ is commutative. (You correctly show that $\phi(R)$ is commutative, which is enough... I actually only read the last line since that is what your question regarded). The main point is that you have to show $\phi(u^{-1})=(\phi(u))^{-1}$. You can’t start with an inverse...

Comment: @Clayton Oh yes, you're right! I should have said that since $R$ is commutative, then $\phi(R)$ is commutative. That is just a proposition for ring homs!

Comment: @Clayton That makes sense. Thank you for looking at my solution carefully and pointing that out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning looks solid, especially after it takes into account Clayton's (justified) nitpicks.

There are a couple ways of getting this result.  My preferred way would be to take advantage of the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem_2): $R/\ker(\phi) \cong \text{Im}(\phi)$.  Note that $\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal, and the only two ideals of a field are $\{0\}$ and the whole field$^\dagger$.  Since $\phi(R) \neq \{0_S\}$, we cannot have $\ker(\phi) = R$.  This forces $\ker(\phi) = \{0\}$, from which we can conclude $R \cong \phi(R)$ per the theorem.

---

$^\dagger$*Proof*:

Let $F$ be a field and $I \subseteq F$ a nonzero ideal.  Then $x \in I$ for some nonzero $x \in F$.  Since $F$ is a field, $x^{-1} \in F$, and we'll have $xx^{-1} = 1$ as an element of $I$.  Hence, $1 \cdot y \in I$ for all $y \in F \implies I = F$.